# connect 3 inch ABS pipe to only 0.5 inch exposed pipe

Tags: plumbing, abs

I would like to cut an existing pipe and install a coupler to connect 2 pieces of 3 inch ABS. I would like to make the connection where I am pointing on the image.

Is that enough pipe to connect to (approx 0.5 inch)? I would like to avoid going back to the main if possible.

[image]

Comment: Is that threaded pipe between?  (Hard to tell from all the dirt.)

Comment: No just reg 3 inch abs

Comment: How good is that joint in the piece under the finger?  Any chance it will release with some wiggling and twisting?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not. If you read the manufacturers' instruction on the ABS cement it says to seat the pipe completely in the hub.

Now... I have cheated the above instruction on more than one occasion but never to that extent. If you are careful, gluing to 1/2" of pipe will probably not leak immediately. The problem is that the strength of the joint will be compromised and any movement (due to soil movement, expansion/contraction of pipe with temp changes, etc.) could cause failure.

I say you should "bite the bullet" and cut back to the next available spot where you have some pipe to work with. You will likely have to rebuild that whole junction area.

Answer (score 0):

0.5 inches is not enough of a pipe length to bond on a new fitting. Full insertion depth for a new fitting flange is on the order of 1.25 to 1.5 inches.

You should consider adapting your new connections off to the right side of the picture where there is more of a straight section of pipe to work with. Trying to rework at that Y connection will lead to a nightmare of taking out and replacing way more than I think you want to get into.

Answer (score 0):

you can cut through that 22 degree bend  and then cut the bell end off that exsisting pipe and leave in place, i just cut 2 -6 slits in the remaining piece of the 22 bend and chisel off the pieces , you gotta know what you’re doing though.